# Error whilst saving contact

Tags: drupal, geocoding

Since yesterday I'am getting the following error when I save contact:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: ret in CRM_Utils_Geocode_Yahoo::format() (regel 155 van /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Geocode/Yahoo.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: ret in CRM_Utils_Geocode_Yahoo::format() (regel 156 van /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Geocode/Yahoo.php).
```

Comment: Was something changed on the server? php version, php.ini changes? Does the geocode still work?

Comment: No PHP updates, I did upgrade from 4.6.13 to 4.7.2. But was already having this error before I upgraded to 4.7.2. Geocoding isn't working anymore.

Found some errors in the apache log; some permission errors.. Looking into that.

Comment: yeah, I looked in the code, you could get that warning if the yahoo geocoding itself failed.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Mapping and Geocoding Providers setting using below link.

your-site-name/civicrm/admin/setting/mapping?reset=1

Change Geocoding Provider to google and then save your contact.

[image]

Comment: That worked, but I use the Yahoo service to get correct Postal Codes. Not a must have, but nice to have so can live with using Google for now :).

Comment: User Below combination for Mapping and Geocoding Providers setting and then test.

Mapping Provider : Open street

Geocoding Providers : Yahoo